# Sometimes receiving duplicate logs using solana_client::nonblocking::pubsub_client::PubsubClient

Tags: websocket, logs, solana-client

I am using [solana_client v1.10.34 nonblocking PubsubClient](https://docs.rs/solana-client/1.10.34/solana_client/nonblocking/pubsub_client/index.html) to subscribe to program logs and I am **sometimes** seeing duplicate logs with the same metadata but 1 slot apart. Is this a bug?

Ps: Must use this version due to another dependency setting max versions on solana crates.

Answer (score 1):

The WebSocket indeed seems to be extremely buggy. I sometimes don't even receive notifications, and then sometimes I get duplicates too.

Could you check if the subscription ID is the same for both?